# Cant find logo upload option on martfury wordpress theme

Tags: wordpress, themes

im was trying to change the martfury wordpress theme header logo. but i cant find logo upload option in there.
im using martfury GPL license theme

can anyone know the issue?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can go to
Appearance > Customize > Header > Logo.

From there you can upload the logo image.